# How to configure multiple kafka consumer in application.yml file

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Actually i have a  springboot based  micro-service , and i have used kafka to produce/consume data from different system.
Now my question is i have two different topics and based on topics i have two different consumer classes to  consume data,

how to define multiple consumer properties  in `application.yml` file ?

I configured for one consumer in `application.yml` like  below  :-

```
spring:
    kafka:
         consumer:
            bootstrapservers: http://199.968.98.101:9092
            group-id: groupid-QA-02
            auto-offset-reset: latest
            key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

I am using `@KafkaListener` in my consumer classes

example of consumer method which i used in code
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic.b2b_tf_ta_req}", groupId = "${app.topic.groupoId}")
    public void consume(String message) throws Exception {

```
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!!! Can you add the consumer code to the question?

Comment: By the way, `bootstrapservers` isn't a valid property, and doesn't use `http://`

Comment: mrsrinivas i have added consumer method code in question which i am using in my consumer class

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know bootstrap-servers accept comma separated list of servers
i.e. if you set it to server1:9092,server2:9092 kafka should connect to all of them

Comment: i would like to handle multiple consumer configuration not bootstrap-servers